# Angular2 webpack: how to import bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

I'm using [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) to build my project and I want to use bootstrap as well.

I install [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) as `npm install ng2-bootstrap --save`. Since the `ng2-bootstrap` only has some directives and it requires the "real" `.css` file of bootstrap to style it (but its author seems to assume we have had it), so I install bootstrap as `npm install bootstrap --save`.

Now, my question is how to import the "real" bootstrap `.css` file to my project, so that `ng2-bootstrap` can use it.

I tried several ways:

1. copy the `bootstrap.min.css` file from `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css` folder to my `src/assets/css` folder and add `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` to my `index.html`. This way works but my concern is that the `bootstrap.min.css` file won't be managed by `npm` any more. I have to manually update it in future.
2. Another attempt is requiring it from my `app.component.ts` like

   styles: [
       require('./app.style.css'),
       require('../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
   ],

but it can't be resolved.

3. last try is adding `import 'bootstrap';` to `vendor.browser.ts` just like `import '@angular/core';` in it. But it failed either. It seems that the `bootstrap` is not a package like `@angular2/core` that I can easily import it.

So, my question comes down to how to import/load `bootstrap` in webpack, so that it can be used by `ng2-bootstrap` and other components in my project and it can also be upgraded by using npm.

Comment: Regarding number 2.  Are you sure you can't import css directly from node_modules?  I have no problem doing this.

Comment: @Helzgate I can't. How do you import it, is it like `require('../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')`?

Comment: I don't know, it just works, i've been using it this way in many places for some time in my app (and yes i'm talking about from node_modules).  Are you absolutely sure you have enough elipses?  I would try adding some more ../ and trying that, or subtracting some.  Pay attention to the error too, maybe it is loading the css but you are running into some other error.

Comment: Here's what I would do --> git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter.git  <-- then I would get this new cloned demo working, then I would test out your css within this demo app and if you get it working (which I'm sure you will), hopefully you'll find the missing problem by comparing the webpack.config files to your project config files, or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

you need to use **css-loader** 
download **css-loader** by using, i did some test in my angular 2 and it work you need some loaders

```
npm install css-loader style-loader url-loader file-loader  --save-dev
```

then in your webpack.config you can use loader like this

```
 loaders: [
    {test: /\.css$/, loader:   ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
    {test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
    {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
    {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
    {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
    {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw',exclude: /node_modules/},
    {test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,loader : 'file-loader'},
]
```

you can load your bootstrap file where you are going to use it with 
and you can use bootstrap in your class like

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
    @Component({
        selector: "sg-nav",
        template: `
                    <div class="container"></div>`,
    })
    export class NavComponent {
        public name: string = "MR.Js";
    }
```

[here you can read how it works with css loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader)

[working example with bootstrap](http://[here%20is%20my%20example](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed))

Comment: can you tell how to use this css loader with angular-cli.i a not able to refer to my bootstrap in node_modules

Comment: This solution is similar to my No. 1 solution. The `.css` is loaded but it's loaded from `src` folder rather than from `node_modules/bootstrap`. So, if I update version in `package.json` and `npm install`, the css file won't get updated.

Comment: i have implemented bootstrap in my angular2 project and edited my answer to show you how it work. try it!

Answer (score 0):

`import 'bootstrap';` would refer to Bootstrap's JS entry point, not its CSS. Try number 3 with

```
import 'bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

instead.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get `ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`. The css file is in `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` but it seems that we can't import a `.css` file in a `.ts` file. It can't be resolved.

Comment: but how to add jquery? When I import files to vendor I get `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` but Css works just fine

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try like this

```
import 'bootstrap';
import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

the first 'import' will import the 'bootstrap' module(maybe refer to bootstrap.js);

the second one may import the css.

and in your webpack.config.js you can use loader

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up via Webpack, but this requires installing and adding loaders to your webpack.config.js (css-loaders, style-loaders, url-loaders, file-loaders), then importing the bootstrap.min.css file and bootstrap files in your vendor.ts.

I think this is pretty verbose.
Rather than the above, you could just simply install (eg using npm) and add the one line below your scripts (the minified webpack js files) to your index.html

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but I'm using `bower` to handle css-related libs (e.g. bootstrap, font-awesome) in my ng2 project.

Set your .bowerrc to save files into: `src/assets/lib` (for example) like this:

```
{
    "directory": "src/assets/lib",
}
```

Then install bower with npm.

`npm install bower --save-dev`

And then you can install bootstrap with:

`bower install bootstrap --save` to add (and if you want to pin the version number) to your bower.json file.

The nice thing about this solution is that bower handles all dependencies for you (for example, it would automatically add jquery to your lib directory)

Then you can manually add your links in your `index.html`, as you already did:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`

I added the `src/assets/lib` folder to my `.gitignore` ... and for installing/deploying, I run `bower install`.