# How to import bootstrap 3.3.7 module - to be used in angular2 component

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm, angular-cli

I have a trouble importing bootstrap 3.3.7 module and use it:

In **package.json**: I have bootstrap 3.3.7 as dependency:

```
{
  "name": "plan",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
      "start": "ng serve",
      "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
      "test": "ng test",
      "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
      "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
      "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
      "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
      "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
      "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
      "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
      "angular2-text-mask": "^1.0.1",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
      "jquery": "^3.1.1",
      "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
      "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
      "tether": "^1.3.7",
      "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
      "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
      "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
      "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
      "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
      "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
      "karma": "1.2.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
      "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
      "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
      "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
      "protractor": "4.0.9",
      "ts-node": "1.2.1",
      "tslint": "3.13.0",
      "typescript": "~2.0.3",
      "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

And in **app.modules.ts** I have the following error when trying to import the module:

**Error:** Cannot find module ../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap
at line 16 col 27

[image]

I have already looked to some questions in SO but it didn't help

[Angular2 webpack: how to import bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537355/angular2-webpack-how-to-import-bootstrap-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#loaders

In your webpack.config.js you should

> teach it to process such files into JavaScript with loaders

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/
    loaders: 'ts'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/
    loaders: 'style!css'
  }
]
```

And do you imports like this:

```
import 'uiframework/dist/uiframework.css';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can import it as a global library as described in the angular-cli [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation) by customizing the `angular-cli.json` file.

Add the script files to `apps[0].scripts`:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Than add the Bootstrap CSS to the `apps[0].styles` array:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
```